# Escrow & multisig contracts

Tags: nearprotocol

How would one go about building an escrow and multisig contract on NEAR?
E.g. in comparison to building the contract in Solidity; what would be needed, are there any examples?

Answer (score 0):

I can't compare this for solidity. But on NEAR multisig contract can be implemented either using multiple AccessKeys or using multiple predecessors.

The following steps are needed:

1. Propose an action `e.g. transfer X to Y` to the contract by calling `propose()` on the contract. This should return a `proposal_id`
2. Aggregate approvals for the `proposal_id` using `approve()` or `reject()` calls.
3. Once necessary amount of approvals are collected. A caller can call `issue` and pass the `proposal_id`, it will issue the action and close the proposal.

Answer (score 0):

Seems there are two questions here, for escrow and multisig. Evgeny has taken on the multisig part.
We *do* have a simple example of escrow on NEAR written in Rust.
This example has no frontend but provides the lower-level CLI commands needed to show an escrow in use.

https://examples.nearprotocol.com/rust-fungible-token

Answer (score 0):

There is an example of multisig contract now here written in Rust - https://github.com/near/core-contracts/tree/master/multisig

The main benefit and why it becomes way simpler, is that NEAR Accounts already maintain set of keys per account. Contract just needs to manage the requests and execute them when enough confirmation have been received.